# Scrapy pipeline to MySQL - Can't find answer

Tags: python, scrapy

I've looked around for the answer on this and can't find the answer.  As I mentioned yesterday I am  new to scrapy and python so the answer may be out there but I'm not catching on.

Ive written my spider which is working just fine. Here is my pipeline....

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class somepipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='user', 'passwd', 'dbname', 'host', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):    
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO sometable (title, link, desc)  
                            VALUES (%s, %s)""", 
                           (item['title'].encode('utf-8'), 
                            item['link'].encode('utf-8'),
                            item['desc'].encode('utf-8'))

            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        return item
```

Heres my settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'somebot'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['somespider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'somespider.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['myproject.pipeline.somepipeline']
```

However when I run this I get a:
    No module named pipeline error

Found an answer similar but it was for an image class and I just want HTML data.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to download another module or something? Appreciate the help. If I'm close just give me an elbow.

Comment: Where is this file? Is it contained in `/path/to/somewhere/myproject/pipeline'? And are these pacakages, i.e. are there `__init__.py` files in `myproject/` and `pipeline` (if pipeline is a directory)?

Comment: The path was projectdirectory/project(with scrappy.cfg)/ and inside there are the pipeline.py and all the expected files with the .pyc files as well.  Per another post I deleted the .pyc files and ran it again. Same issue.

Comment: If the script you are running is in `projectdirectory/project`, then the correct name for ITEM_PIPELINES should be `pipeline.somepipeline` and the `pipeline` directory should have the `__init__.py` file. It seems you should enter the path to a python package, read up on that.

Comment: My __init__.py file is empty. Should something be in there and is that the file I need to investigate? Or the path to a python package?

Answer (score 2):

The Scrapy tutorial has a typo: It has to be 'pipelineS'

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['myproject.pipelines.somepipeline']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "pipeline" file. It should be "pipelines". So you need to change

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['myproject.pipeline.somepipeline']
```

to

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['myproject.pipelines.somepipeline']
```

Comment: Ok.  that was my mistake in some dedug I was trying to do.  Put it back to pipelines and now I am getting a: `code` self.conn.commit() error.  I am currently looking up this syntax error.

Comment: Now I am getting 
    `self.conn=MySQLdb.connect(user= 'test', 'test', 'test', 'localhost')
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` error                                                                                                                                      Heres my code `class mypipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.conn=MySQLdb.connect(user= 'test', 'test', 'test', 'localhost')
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()`                                                   COMPLETELY lost on this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The syntax of MySQLdb.connect might be incorrect. Please try to use this one:

import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(
                  host=HOST,
                  user=USERNAME,
                  passwd=PASSWORD,
                  db=DB,
                  cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                  charset='utf8',
                  use_unicode=True
                  )

Answer (score 0):

The correct directory path should be something like this:

```
myproject/
     scrapy.cfg  
     myproject/
         __init__.py
         items.py
         pipeline.py
         settings.py
         spiders/
            spider.py
```

On a different note, can you confirm that your spider is working correctly? For example, if you were to comment out the ITEM_PIPELINES setting, does your spider work and produce the expected output?

Comment: Hey @talvalin. Thanks for your help again.  The file structure is correct. I am able to run to spider just fine.  If I take out the pipeline I can watch the spider run just fine, I see all the data constructed how I need in it. However, If I do a `code` scrapy crawl myproject --> abc.txt I end up with a blank file versus if I run it with the command from the scrapy tutorial I end up with a cached webpage.  Trying to figure out the middle ground!

Comment: Ok quick update.  One error I found was that I have not run `pip install mysql-python` or `easy_install mysql-python` regardless it didnt matter because I had not installed `libmysqlclient-dev` SOOOO I did all that inclluding the appropriate `-U` commands AND now I'm back to square one with SyntaxError: invalid syntax. More to follow.

Comment: If you're getting an invalid syntax error in your pipeline code, it means that the import is working. Is that the case?